# How to read Bootstrap component data options via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched everywhere for an official documentation on how to do it, but I haven't encountered any... I want to be able to read a Bootstrap component's options using jQuery, for example:

```
$(element).popover({placement: 'top', trigger: 'manual', content: 'sample content'});
$(element).popover('show');
```

How do I retrieve the placement and trigger options via jQuery? I hacked my way into Chrome's inspector by watching the expression `$(element).data()` and found out that I could do this:

```
var placement = $(element).data('bs.popover').options.placement;
```

The line above certainly does the job, but I'm wary if this is the "official" way of going about it.  I want to avoid having to update a bunch of scripts in case I had to update Bootstrap in the future by just dropping in new files.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you're going to find an *official* way is if Bootstrap documents it. What you've found certainly seems like it would be expected to work, but I don't know that you're going to be able to find a guarantee.

Comment: I guess you're right.  Maybe I should rephrase my question.  I had the false impression that I could ask that question and expect somebody from bootstrap, or somebody who had really extensive experience to answer it.  I'm sorry...

Comment: If you leave this question here long enough, it's possible that one of the developers may come by and give the answer you're looking for. You may also want to check the Bootstrap forums, if you haven't already. If you get an official answer, you should post it here.